# Coefficient of $Y \sim X$ versus coefficient of $X \sim Y$

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-regression

Let's consider two variables $X, Y$ such that $EX = EY = 0$, $VarX = VarY = 1$

Moreover, when considering OLS model without intercept $Y \sim X$ we obtained parameter $\beta$.

Thing that I want to investigate is connection between parameter $\beta$ and parameter $\hat \beta$ obtained from regression $X \sim Y$.

**My solution**

If $\beta$ and $\hat \beta$ are solutions of OLS problems then we have that:

$$\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$$

$$\hat \beta = (Y^TY)^{-1}Y^TX$$

Then we have that:

$$\beta \hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY(Y^TY)^{-1}Y^TX = X^{-1}X^TX^TYY^{-1}Y^TX = 1$$

So we have that $\hat \beta = \frac{1}{\beta}$.

And I'm not sure if my solution is correct since, I check it in R to obtain that:

```
y <- rnorm(1000000)
k <- rnorm(1000000)
lm(y~ 0 + k)$coefficients == 1 / lm(k~0 + y)$coefficients
FALSE
```

Could you please tell me where do I have an error?

**EDIT**

As I understood problem in my calculations is that I'm trying to invert vectors, which are invertible. So my another idea driven by @GoldenRatio is that we know that:

$$\beta = \frac{\textrm{cov}(X, Y)}{\textrm{Var}X} = E[XY]$$

as well as

$$\hat \beta = \frac{\textrm{cov}(X, Y)}{\textrm{Var}Y} = E[XY]$$

So out of it we would have that $\beta = \hat \beta$. Is it right?

Comment: How do you take the inverse of a vector?

Comment: In the regression without intercept, you will find that in the model $E(y) = \beta x$ you have $\hat \beta = \dfrac{x^\intercal y}{x^\intercal x} = \dfrac{s_{x,y}}{s_{x,x}}$ where $s_{x,y}$ and $s_{x,x}$ are the sample covariance and variance of $(x,y)$ and $x$, resp. If you now want $E(x) = y \mu,$ you will find $\hat \mu = \dfrac{s_{x,y}}{s_{y, y}}.$ Is $\hat \mu \hat \beta = 1$?

Comment: (Note that you are working with both $x$ and $y$ vectors, and $\beta, \mu$ are scalars here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation doesn't make sense for a few reasons, one of which is the fact that a $n\times 1$ vector is not invertible ($n>1$). Assuming for simplicity that each regression uses a single regressor and no intercept (so that what you are calling $\beta,\hat\beta$ are scalars),
we can't say how the objects

$$\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_iY_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i^2},\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_iY_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i Y_i^2}.$$
compare since they are defined at the sample level; the numerators are the same, but we can't say how the denominators compare.

However, assuming $(X_i,Y_i)$ iid,  and $\text{Var}(X_i)=\text{Var}(Y_i)=1,E[X_i]=E[Y_i]=0$, WLLN tells us the above objects have the same limit in probability, namely
$$\frac{E[X_iY_i]}{E[X_i^2]}=\frac{E[X_iY_i]}{E[Y_i^2]}=\text{Cov}(X_i,Y_i).$$

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

In this setup $y,k$ which are random variables will never find TRUE in your logical test and the reason is that both regressions calculate the conditional expectation given something fixed not a random.

Comment: Indeed.The lm function in R calculate the $E(Y|X=x)$.Seeding the rvs would solve it.